# clustering comparison

Tags: r, clustering

I was wondering if there is a method to compare clustering results.
I initially tried to use the Rand index but my results do not satisfy the conditions to use this method.

In my specific case, I have to lists.  The lists contain the indexes of the cluster for each element in the data. Same line(row), in each list, corresponds to the same element in the original data.

In one list I have "k" clusters, in the other I have "n>k" clusters.

The cluster methods are very different such that, for instance, for the lines that show a cluster index value of "A" the other list doesn't necessarily have "A" or a number close to "A".

I am putting here some R code hoping that this helps in clarifying my question.
If you write this in R:

```
rand.index(sample(1:100, 20, replace=TRUE), sample(1:150, 20, replace=TRUE))
```

You get an index of 0.98, although the groups are completely random.

Is there another method to compare clustering results that overcome this difficulty?

EDIT:
In the comments, they asked me to provide my data.  I can't provide them all, just a subset.  The two lists are approximately 4M long.

```
> head(clustering_method1, 20)
   Index Cluster
1      2       5
2      3      19
3      4      25
4      5      25
5      6      31
6      7      72
7      8      61
8      9      38
9     10      92
10    11      25
11    12      99
12    13      57
13    14      10
14    16       6
15    17      21
16    18      21
17    19      27
18    20      17
19    21       5
20    22      25
> head(clustering_method2,20)
   Index Cluster
1      2     240
2      3     196
3      4      14
4      5     117
5      6      27
6      7       0
7      8     143
8      9      15
9     10     157
10    11      95
11    12       0
12    13      22
13    14     149
14    16      23
15    17       7
16    18      46
17    19       2
18    20      67
19    21     240
20    22     117
```

Comment: If you have different clusters then you cannot really compare these two vectors. Also, you may want to try the Adjusted Rand Index.

Comment: Normalized mutual information

Comment: Give an example of your data. Not a code, the data itself.

Comment: If you give me a negative vote I would happy to understand why.  Was the question not clear enough? Not worth enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to my question was to use the Jaccard index.
The Jaccard index is calculated used 4 parameters, let's call them s11, s00, s10, and s01.
The two vectors to be compared must be of the same size.
Hereafter there is a pseudocode to estimate the Jaccard index.
The variable "size" in the for loop is the length of the vectors (that, as I said, must be of the same length).
Then there are the two "clustering_method" 1 and 2.

```
for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
  for(int j=i+1; j<size; ++j){
    if(clustering_method1[i] == clustering_method1[j] && clustering_method2[i] == clustering_method2[j])
      s11++;
    if(clustering_method1[i] != clustering_method1[j] && clustering_method2[i] != clustering_method2[j])
      s00++;
    if(clustering_method1[i] == clustering_method1[j] && clustering_method2[i] != clustering_method2[j])
      s10++;
    if(clustering_method1[i] != clustering_method1[j] && clustering_method2[i] == clustering_method2[j])
      s01++;
  }
}
jaccard=float(s11)/float(s11+s10+s01);
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use the Rand index itself - always use the **adjusted for chance** version. ARI and AMI are certainly the right choices for your problem.

The similarity of almost 1 on your toy example is **correct**:

You sample 20 values from 100 respectively 150 "clusters". This means that **almost every object is its own cluster**. Now because cluster numbers are random anyway, that means these results are almost identical! Both random results that you generated say the data does not cluster, that is a high agreement. If you want more intuitive results, choose k<